# Changing the separator color/thickness for a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there a way to change the color/thickness of some of my `UITableViewCell` separators, but not all? Currently, I'm able to use `[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor greycolor]];` to set the color of all of my UITableView separators to Red, but I want the separator at the bottom to be a slightly darker grey. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but only if you create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and implement custom drawing in `-drawRect:`